# Use variables inside :nth-child(n + x) pseudo class

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

At the moment I have a snippet of LESS that will basically shift each subsequent child further down from the top:

```
    &:nth-child(n+2) {
        top: @alertTop + 10px;
    }

    &:nth-child(n+3) {
        top: @alertTop + 20px;
    }

    &:nth-child(n+4) {
        top: @alertTop + 30px;
    }
```

Is there anyway to use the 'x' part of 'n+x' in the calculation so that I don't have to manually add these?

I.e. something like:

```
    &:nth-child(n+x) {
        top: @alertTop + (x * 5px);
    }
```

LESS/CSS only methods preferred.

Comment: Check on this solution which apply a scss solution to a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973340/css-increment-nth-child-attribute-values/26973469#26973469

Comment: You don't need `n+` in your equation.

Comment: Check out [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66576570/1026132) for CSS variables modified from HTML

Answer (score 3):

[From the documentation](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature): Create a mixin that calls itself, along with a guard expression:

**LESS**

```
#test {
  @child-count: 5;
  @child-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  height: @child-count * @child-height;
  > div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: @child-height;
    background: red;
  }
  .loop(@i) when (@i <=5) {
    > :nth-child(@{i}) {
      top: (@i - 1) * @child-height;
    }
    .loop(@i + 1);
  }
  .loop(1);
}
```

**Result**

```css
#test {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
}
#test > div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
#test > :nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}
#test > :nth-child(2) {
  top: 100px;
}
#test > :nth-child(3) {
  top: 200px;
}
#test > :nth-child(4) {
  top: 300px;
}
#test > :nth-child(5) {
  top: 400px;
}
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEWjvY)