# Is there a way to use the "n" value in :nth-child(n)?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to create a fold effect.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minzojian/1osccoov/2/)

There are 4 blue cards, so I created 4 classes to set the location. I want to make it smarter, in case there would be more than 4 cards. In CSS, I tried this.

```
.card:nth-child(n){
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(n*10)px;
    top: calc(n*10)px;
}
```

However, it does not work. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: CSS can't do that. Use a framework like SCSS/SASS/LESS.

Comment: JavaScript could be an alternative

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xmj5u2Lg/2/) is a JavaScript code to do that.

Comment: using lESS http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYKzPq

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CSS doesn't have support for variables. You could use Less/SASS loops and define it for n up to some value, but that would output almost the same CSS multiple times. Here is [Codepen](https://codepen.io/markogresak/pen/GRZXBaR?editors=1100) example.

SCSS code to support up to 10 cards:

```
$n: 10;

@for $i from 1 through $n {
  .card:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px * $i;
    top: 10px * $i;
  }
}
```

But are you sure your approach is correct? Maybe you want to take a step back and look for a different approach. Because this still doesn't scale dynamically, you'll have to predict or limit *n* to some value. If you were to pick large *n*, it would result in a big CSS file, which equals longer load times.

Comment: thanks,i will take that.
i just google it and i will try to use LESS

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @Nicicalu. I have fixed the link to now point to a codepen example. For some reason, `@for` does not work on JSFiddle. Sadly, there's no support for SCSS with stackoverflow snippets.

Comment: @Marko Gresak Thanks for the quick response! Have a nice week

Answer (score 7):

To leave calculations in CSS, you can use CSS variables: `calc( var(--n) * 10px );`. You'll still have to define `--n` manually either via JS or by having it predefined in the HTML, but this way it feels more declarative, as no actual styling make it to JS code:

```js
function add() {
  var parent = document.querySelector('.container');
  var child = document.createElement('div');
  child.classList.add('child');
  child.style.setProperty('--n', parent.children.length);
  parent.appendChild(child);
}
```

```css
.child {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc( var(--n) * 30px + 100px );
  top: calc( var(--n) * 30px );
  background-color: red;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="add()">Add more</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="child" style="--n: 0;"></div>
  <div class="child" style="--n: 1;"></div>
  <div class="child" style="--n: 2;"></div>
</div>
```

Browser [support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) is pretty decent: every major browser nowadays has it.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using CSS custom properties and a little snippet:

```css
:root {
  --index: 0;
}

*:nth-child(1) {
  --index: 0;
}

*:nth-child(2) {
  --index: 1;
}

*:nth-child(3) {
  --index: 2;
}
```

You declare it once, for the number of children you might expect to have and then use like that:

```css
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100px * var(--index));
}
```

Demo:
https://codepen.io/waterplea/pen/KKNqqQy

Comment: Generate that snippet: `console.log([...Array(25)].map((_,i) => \`*:nth-child(${i+1}) { --index: ${i}; }\`).join('\n'))`

Answer (score 4):

Try this method using JavaScript

```js
var cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');

for(i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    cards[i].style.position = 'absolute';
    cards[i].style.left = String(i * 10) + 'px';
    cards[i].style.top = String(i * 10) + 'px';
}
```

```css
.card{
    opacity:0.5;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:blue;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:40px;
    height:60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
    <div class="card card1" ></div>
    <div class="card card2" ></div>
    <div class="card card3" ></div>
    <div class="card card4" ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't exactly know what are going to do with it, but you could achieve the same effect by nesting divs

```css
.card {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
    border:1px solid red;
    width:40px;
    height:60px;
}
.card > .card {
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:10px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="holder">
        <div class="card card1" >
            <div class="card card2">  
                <div class="card card3" >
                    <div class="card card4" >
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xmj5u2Lg/7/

Comment: Remove `card1` and you've just removed all the cards. I doubt that's a desired functionality.

Comment: Well, the thing is I don't know what is he going to do with it. It might be hard to animate this, but as for the graphical effect it is as simple as it can get, I guess. It would get messy later in the html with the deck size increment, but It should 'work' as long as `.card` is within another `.card`

Comment: On that I agree, it's hard to figure out the correct way without details on what OP wants to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

CSS variables can be set with HTML and JavaScript:

```
<style>
.card:nth-child(n){
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(var(--index)*10px);
    top: calc(var(--index)*10px);
}
</style>

<div class="card" style="--index: 0"></div>
<div class="card" style="--index: 1"></div>
```

**UPDATE** Moved px into the calc, by @Kenneth suggestion

Comment: "px" should move into the calc