# How to place elements in a circle as on a clock face with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am new to coding. I searched for hours on the internet but couldn't find a clear and simple way to design a clock face with numbers.

I mean how to put 12 or 24 numbers on a clock **with CSS** (not SCSS)? I know I can copy/paste codes but I really want to figure it out.

Is it possible to design perfect circular objects with 24 or 12 hours?

Thank you for your help.

I tried to place number with degrees or top and left elements but it didn't work perfectly.

Comment: Here, pick what you like, if you do not want to copy/paste it then analyze it and write it yourself...https://freefrontend.com/css-clocks/

Comment: CSS is not really the best option for the task (imo) - perhaps use Javascript and a `canvas`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS variables in combination with nth-child for that:

```css
body{
    color:white;
}
#clock{
    width:100%;
    aspect-ratio:1 / 1;
    background-color:blue;
    border-radius:100%;
    position:relative;
}
:nth-child(1) { --nth-child: 1 }
:nth-child(2) { --nth-child: 2 }
:nth-child(3) { --nth-child: 3 }
:nth-child(4) { --nth-child: 4 }
:nth-child(5) { --nth-child: 5}
:nth-child(6) { --nth-child: 6 }
:nth-child(7) { --nth-child: 7 }
:nth-child(8) { --nth-child: 8 }
:nth-child(9) { --nth-child: 9 }
:nth-child(10) { --nth-child: 10 }
:nth-child(11) { --nth-child: 11 }
:nth-child(12) { --nth-child: 12 }


.hour{
    left:45%;
    top:45%;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    width:10%;
    height:10%;
    background-color:black;
    border-radius:100%;
    transform:rotateZ(calc((var(--nth-child) + 6)*calc(360/12)*1deg))
            translateY(400%)
            rotateZ(calc((var(--nth-child) + 6)*calc(360/12)*-1deg));
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="clock">
    <div class="hour">1</div>
    <div class="hour">2</div>
    <div class="hour">3</div>
    <div class="hour">4</div>
    <div class="hour">5</div>
    <div class="hour">6</div>
    <div class="hour">7</div>
    <div class="hour">8</div>
    <div class="hour">9</div>
    <div class="hour">10</div>
    <div class="hour">11</div>
    <div class="hour">12</div>
   
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

If you want to simplify the code some more you can use javascript like in this answer:
[Is there a way to use the "n" value in :nth-child(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002684/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-n-value-in-nth-childnn)

Answer (score 0):

its possible! here's the code

HTML

```
 <div class="parent">
        <div class="clock">
            <span style="--n:1">1</span>
            <span style="--n:2">2</span>
            <span style="--n:3">3</span>
            <span style="--n:4">4</span>
            <span style="--n:5">5</span>
            <span style="--n:6">6</span>
            <span style="--n:7">7</span>
            <span style="--n:8">8</span>
            <span style="--n:9">9</span>
            <span style="--n:10">10</span>
            <span style="--n:11">11</span>
            <span style="--n:12">12</span>
           
        </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
.parent{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #EFF6FF;
    position: relative;   
    padding: 10px; 
}
.clock{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
.clock span{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #155674;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(calc(var(--n) * 30deg));
    transform-origin: 0 240px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```