# How to extend a list of object array using for loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

```
// First i=0
let posi_val=[{top: '3px', left: '2px'}];
// Second i=1
let posi_val=[{top: '3px', left: '2px'},{top: '6px', left: '4px'}];
// Third i=2
let posi_val=[{top: '3px', left: '2px'},{top: '6px', left: '4px'},{top: '12px', left: '8px'}];
```

Dear all, the above code is part of code to create css class (multiple red dots) on different postion, may I ask how to extend the **list of object arrays as shown in the example** above such that it is using **for loop** and the **top and left numbers are extended by 2 times the previous value so its 3,6,12 and 2,4,8 px and so on?**

I have tried using JSON.parse to rewrite the entire string again but its quite confusing, so are there any simpler method to construct this array? A demo can be found at codepen [here](https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/wvxpwaW?editors=0012).

Comment: Try looking here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002684/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-n-value-in-nth-childn. If you want to stick to js consider this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28002855/11298974 and use `posi_val.push({})` to add an element at the end of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like that ?

```js
console.log(  creatList( 5 )  )

function creatList( counter )
  {
  let t= 3, l= 2, res= [];
  for(let i=0;i<counter;i++)
    {
    res.push( {top:`${t}px`,left:`${l}px`} );
    t *=2, l *=2;
    }
  return res
  }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

the same, in a "single" line of code.

All values being in binary, the left shift is equivalent to a multiplication by 2.

```js
const creatList = length => 
  Array.from({length},(_,i)=>({top:`${3<<i}px`,left:`${2<<i}px`}));

console.log(  creatList( 5 )  )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

Comment: Nice!! @Mister Jojo . We need such refreshers on lesser used code constructs from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```js
const cssPositions = (initialTop, initialLeft, count) => {
    let posi_val = [];
    for(i=0; i<count; i++){
        cssObj = { top: `${initialTop}px`, left: `${initialLeft}px` };

        initialTop += initialTop;
        initialLeft += initialLeft;

        posi_val.push(cssObj);
    }
  
  return posi_val;
}

// Calling the function 
console.log(cssPositions(3,2,3));
```