# CSS property value based on the child --index. Can it be done purelly with CSS or at least Sass?

Tags: css, sass

I've built a Counter widget that has some animations options. One of those are the numbers appearing, **one at a time**. To achive this, the HTML output separates each number on it's own span tag.

```
<span class="ui-e-num"> 
    <span>1</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>5</span>
    <span>+</span>
</span>
```

The CSS is:

```
.ui-e-num span {
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
    translate: 0 -60px;
    text-shadow: 0 15px 10px var(--parent-num-color);
    filter: blur(2px);
    transition: translate 320ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.17, 1), text-shadow 360ms ease-out, filter 360ms ease-out, opacity 200ms ease-in;
}

.ui-e-num.active span {
    opacity: 1;
    translate: 0 0;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
    filter: blur(0);
}
```

The challenge is that all `.ui-e-num` span childs needs a `transition-delay` that is increased for each one. Based on the code I inserted here, the number `<span>1</span>` would have a `transition-delay: 100ms`; the number `<span>1</span>` would have `transition-delay:200ms` and so on.

This can be achieved with JS of course, but I wanted to built it with CSS only, however I can't figure it out how the could would look like.

I've built a sass foreach to achieve this, but it seens like there's a better and more optimized way of doing this with less code.

Comment: you may have a different rule for each index like  `.ui-e-num span:nth-child(1)`, `.ui-e-num span:nth-child(2)` .. and so on ..setting a different `transition-delay: 100ms;` but yet it's not clear how you are setting the `active` class of the element to trigger the transition. Are you aware that's not something you'll achieve with css only? As a side note this should be `transform: translate(0, -60px);`

Comment: Yes I am. The active is beeing set by JS itself. I thought about nth-child(), but since the quantity of numbers are undefined (there could be 2 or more than 10), it isn't a good for me.

Comment: @DiegoD Why should I use transform instead of translate? Is it a bronwser support thing?

Comment: because I was wrong :D ... they are both valid (yet slightly different) but I'm more used to what I suggested before. Talking about the new details that the number of spans could change,  surely the solution setting the custom variable as an inline style, will save you from adding new css rules. I can't see a better way to limit the areas where to write the information and without using js. Drawcak is that you have to respect the order 1,2,3,4 .. while that custom variable could be set via js on document ready. just my 2 cents

Comment: One more thing.. don't forget to reward people that correctly addressed your question. Maybe you don't have enough reputation to give upvotes.. but don't forget to accept the most correct answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no, you can't do that with basic CSS, some CSS compilers (SASS/SCSS) may allow you to write something that gets that result, but would likely create more CSS than you actually need.

However, you can pass in a custom CSS variable to each entry and make use of that in the CSS as if it were a variable increasing over the number of children; it doesn't require any JavaScript.

See below for the snippet:

```js
function toggleClass() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("ui-e-num")[0].classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
.ui-e-num span {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  translate: 0 -60px;
  text-shadow: 0 15px 10px var(--parent-num-color);
  filter: blur(2px);
  transition: translate 320ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.17, 1), text-shadow 360ms ease-out, filter 360ms ease-out, opacity 200ms ease-in;
  /* make use of the `--n` value */
  transition-delay: calc(200ms * var(--n));
}

.ui-e-num.active span {
  opacity: 1;
  translate: 0 0;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
  filter: blur(0);
}
```

```html
<span class="ui-e-num">
  <!-- set the `--n` value here -->
  <span style="--n: 1;">1</span>
  <span style="--n: 2;">3</span>
  <span style="--n: 3">5</span>
  <span style="--n: 4;">+</span>
</span>


<button type="button" onclick="toggleClass();">Toggle Active class</button>
```

Note: I've added in the button just so you can toggle the `active` class on and off.

N.B: This question is quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002684/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-n-value-in-nth-childn), but focuses on `nth-child` for which [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60854493/15291770) was the best inspiration (but it's not the accepted answer on that question)

Comment: I like this approach very much. Haven't thought about it. Thanks a lot! Gonna try it here.

Comment: Thanks, don't forget to mark the answer the answer with the green tick icon

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your result using ***[`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)*** property. Below is the sass code to do it cleanly:

```
@for $i from 1 through 4 { /* Adjust the iteration as per your need. */
    .ui-e-num span:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        transition-delay: #{$i * 100}ms;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that, since there could be from 1 to more than 15 numbers, this approach generates to much unnecessary CSS. But thank you for helping.

Comment: @LucasM.Falbo, it's simple. You can restrict that by just using ***[`css variables`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)***